# Join on subquery in symfony2 with doctrine2

Tags: php, sql, join, doctrine-orm, subquery

I am trying to execute the following SQL in my symfony2 application.

Summary of the SQL is

```
Select the latest currency conversion rate for each branch.
The currencies should be active.
The branches should be verified.
```

Original SQL is

```
SELECT b.id, r1.* FROM rate as r1 JOIN 
 ( SELECT branch, from_currency, to_currency, max ( time ) as latest_time FROM `rate` group by branch, from_currency, to_currency ) as r2 
 ON r1.branch = r2.branch 
    and r1.from_currency = r2.from_currency 
    and r1.to_currency = r2.to_currency 
    and r1.time = r2.latest_time
 join branch b 
    on b.id = r1.branch and b.verified_by is not null
 join currency c1
    on r1.from_currency = c1.id 
 join currency c2
    on r1.to_currency = c2.id
 where c1.active = 1 and c2.active = 1
```

Firstly I tried with querybuilder which doesnt seem to be supported in such cases.
Now I realized that I need to use NativeQuery.
But I am confused on populating the ResultSetMapping. 
I was following http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html but cant really articulate something.

Question is:

- Can anyone please help me to populate the resultsetmapping here?
- Or any better way to fetch the resultset?

P.S. Let me know if I should add the schemas as well. I am skipping it just for the sake of brevity.

Comment: The query builder is part of the Doctrine 2 library, which Symfony uses, but is not part of Symfony itself. (I changed the tag to reflect this.)